# SVG view box crop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, svg, crop

I am doing sticker website for my client. They need image crop within given SVG image. That SVG image is unshaped like Halloween face (see below).

[image]

When i upload an image, it will display within the given image. The rest of the image will hide.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really quite easy with SVG clipPaths. It has good browser support as well, except of course IE.

```css
.defs {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.demo {
    text-align:center;
}
.star image {
    clip-path: url(#star-clip);
}
.hex image {
    clip-path: url(#hex-clip);
}
.heart image {
    clip-path: url(#heart-clip);
}
.shape image {
    clip-path: url(#shape-clip);
}
```

```html
<svg class="defs">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="star-clip">
            <polygon id="star" points="150,7.3 196.4,101.3 300,116.3 225,189.4 242.7,292.7 150,243.9 57.3,292.7 75,189.4 0,116.3 103.6,101.3" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="hex-clip">
            <polygon id="hex" points="222.5,295 77.5,295 5,150 77.5,5 222.5,5 295,150" />
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="heart-clip">
            <path id="heart" d="M248.078,5.883c-36.691-14.739-77.771-0.839-98.517,31.125C128.817,5.044,87.735-8.856,51.043,5.883 C9.354,22.632-10.863,70.009,5.887,111.696c16.06,39.98,143.314,139.607,143.314,139.607l0.359,0.28l0.36-0.28 c0,0,127.251-99.627,143.314-139.607C309.986,70.009,289.768,22.632,248.078,5.883z"/>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="shape-clip">
            <path id="shape" d="M132.9,0.9c-12.5,1-34.7,4.4-44.9,6.7c-33.5,7.6-55.7,28.2-63.8,58.8c-1.8,6.9-2.2,9.7-2.3,20.1c0,10.5,0.2,13.3,2.3,21.6 c9.5,40.7,33.2,90.2,71.5,149.8c10.5,16.4,14.8,21.8,22.8,29.3c4.3,3.9,8.3,6.8,13,9.2l6.9,3.4h10.9c10.9,0,10.9,0,17-2.9 c7.6-3.7,14.3-8.7,21.4-16.2c6.9-7.2,10.5-12.3,21.9-30.3C248,188.7,272,134.3,277.4,96.6c1.2-8.6,0.5-22.4-1.7-31.3 c-5.6-23.4-20.8-41.2-43.6-50.9c-15.3-6.5-27.5-10-44.5-12.5C177.7,0.5,144.9-0.1,132.9,0.9z"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
<div class="demo heart">
    <svg width="300" height="300">
        <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-300-300-4.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="demo star">
    <svg width="300" height="300">
        <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-300-300-10.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="demo hex">
    <svg width="300" height="300">
        <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-300-8.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="demo shape">
    <svg width="300" height="300">
        <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-300-300-6.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

You'll need to define your clipPath and then apply it to your image.  In the demo, I created a separate SVG element that contains all of the shapes as path or polygon definitions and simply applied them using external styles.  You can of course do this in a single SVG, such as:

```
<svg width="120" height="120">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="shape-clip">
            <path id="shape" d="M60,117.4c-20.4,0-44.8-53.6-49-76.4C7.3,21,26.6,4.2,46.9,2.6c7-0.5,19.8-0.2,26.2,0 C93.5,3.4,112.7,21,109,41C104.8,63.8,79.3,117.4,60,117.4z"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-120-120-6.jpg" width="120" height="120" style="clip-path: url(#shape-clip);" />
</svg>
```

Some things to keep in mind:

1. Your defs need to be defined in the source order before they are used (so you can't put them at the end of your page for example).
2. The SVG element defs will not display, but they will take up space in the rendered page.  I just force them out of the document flow with position: absolute and give them a height and width of 0 to make sure they don't mess with my layout.

For more information, you might want to look at these:

- [Clipping and Masking in CSS](http://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/), CSS Tricks
- [SVG Clip Path Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/clip-path.html), Jenkov.com
- [Clipping, Masking and Compositing Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath), W3C

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i need polygon points for my shape. How can i achieve that?

Comment: I use Adobe Illustrator, but there are online tools you can use as well.  There's even an online tool that will convert a png image to svg http://www.online-convert.com/.  Meanwhile, I updated the snippet in this answer with the paths you need.

Comment: Already i used that above said link. but it gives <g> not <defs>. Any ideas???. Me too have Adobe Illustrator. How can i get that point?

Comment: One more thing, i need point for my above image (updated as small image). Could you do that??? Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Actually, I already did give you the paths for your SVG.  See the shape-clip def.  The V in SVG stands for vector, so if you want it to be smaller or larger, just change the height and width of the where you are applying the def.  Also, it seems this answer has helped you, so it is customary to upvote and mark as correct so others can benefit from it in the future.

Comment: Could you tell me clearly... or just post an fiddle plz......... i having deadline for this task :( Also i need points for my image not as d value.

Comment: You can't use a polygon for your image. In SVG, polygons render straight lines between points only.  A path is the only way to render arcs and curves.  Your image has curved edges so you need to use a path element.