# Styling md-icon

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Hello i am using angular material and i want to make the md-icon appears as circle image. I have a sideNav and multiple view. In index.html i have this:

```
<div layout="column" role="main" tabindex="-1" ui-view="" flex>

</div>
```

Where inside i show my views. Now in one of my views i have a toolbar and a list as follow:

```
<md-toolbar md-scroll-shrink>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    </div>
</md-toolbar>

<md-content id="dashboard">
    <md-list>
         <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in dashboard.todos">
             <md-icon md-svg-icon="svg-1" class="avatar"></md-icon>    
         </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</md-content>
```

and the css file for the syling of dashboard.avatar

```
#dashboard .avatar {
   position: relative;
   width: 128px;
   height: 128px;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   zoom:0.70;
   transform: translateZ(0);
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.70);
   -moz-transform:scale(0.70);
}
```

Why does the style not appearing to the icon?
I realized that the id "dashboard" with the class avatar is not working, but when i put all the content html into div tag and set the id dashboard there is working fine but then i have a problem with my view because i have the main div and then another div with the content.

Thank you

Comment: Seems like you have a specificity issue.  In other words, the material css is more specific for the element and thus overriding your css.  The easiest way to fix this is to use the dev tools to inspect the element and see which rules are being applied.  Then you can use the same selectors in your css to override them.

Comment: @jme11 Which element to ispect?

Comment: Well, you're targeting the md-icon, so right-click on one of the icons in your page and see how the directive structures the compiled results.  I'd focus on which ever compiled element has your avatar class first.

Comment: @jme11 This is the result: <md-icon md-svg-icon="svg-4" class="avatar ng-isolate-scope md-default-theme" aria-hidden="true">

Comment: Good, now you have to look at which styles are overriding your styles.  Be aware that it's possible that the directive could be adding inline styles as well.  It's difficult to provide more help without seeing what you see.  So if you have more trouble, creating a demo would be great (a simple Plunkr or something similar).

Comment: @jme11 how can i find which styles are overriding my styles?

Comment: Okay, so I see your css rule and I see the avatar class in that demo, but what I don't see is an id="dashboard" anywhere.

Comment: @jme11 i am sorry check it now

Comment: seems like it's working now...maybe just refresh to reload not from cache.

Comment: @jme11 no the images on dashboard should be circle

Comment: Ah... yeah, as far as I know border-radius doesn't work with SVG elements.  Try clip paths.  Here's an old answer of mine that explains them pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425575/svg-view-box-crop-using-jquery/28432026#28432026

Comment: @jme11 but \if i surround dashboard.html code with div that will work

Comment: I understand, that's why I suggested a clip-path.  I know in the answer I show an additional div surrounding the svg, but you can apply the clip path directly to the avatar class, such as: #dashboard .avatar { clip-path: circle(60px at center); } or using a url like I show in the question but applying it with your SVG selectors.

Comment: Wait, maybe I misunderstood, so you're saying that if you add another div around the content, then the border-radius is applied directly to the svg?  That's kinda weird.  Will take a look.

Comment: if i do my doashboard.html like this <div id="dashboard"><md-toolbar md-scroll-shrink>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    </div>
</md-toolbar>

<md-content >
    <md-list>
         <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in dashboard.todos">
             <md-icon md-svg-icon="svg-1" class="avatar"></md-icon>    
         </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</md-content></div>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, well you taught me something today.  I didn't even realize that border-radius would work on svg elements.

The fix is crazy simple:

Just add one rule to your css:

```
.avatar svg {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: thank you very match. can you explain me why that work?

Comment: Best I can guess, without much in depth research, is that since an inline SVG is essentially it's own xml document, it doesn't inherit the css that is applied to its parent nor does it necessarily care that the parent is clipped by its border-radius.  This makes sense to me, but still doesn't explain why adding another div around your content would make things work for you.  If I have time later, I will take a look at it (because now I'm curious too) and see what's really at the heart of this behavior.